# httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port:

Tags: python, file

i'm trying to do a script which check if many urls exists:

```
import httplib

with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
        connection.request("GET")
        response = connection.getresponse()
        if response.status == 200:
            print '[{}]: '.format(url), "Up!"
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 693, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 721, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//globo.com/galeria/amazonas/a.html
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What format is your `urls.txt` file in?

Comment: have "http:" and "https:" urls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`httplib.HttpConnection` takes the `host` and `port` of the remote URL in its constructor, and not the whole URL.

For your use case, it's easier to use `urllib2.urlopen`.

```
import urllib2

with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        try:
            r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.URLError as e:
            r = e
        if r.code in (200, 401):
            print '[{}]: '.format(url), "Up!"
        elif r.code == 404:
            print '[{}]: '.format(url), "Not Found!"
```

Comment: Hmm! a few of url got `HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized` and the script stop, How to fix?

Comment: See edit: `urlopen` raises `URLError`s on non-"success" responses, but `URLError` contains the HTTP status code as well, so we can do the above.

Comment: Dammit, now is returning: `NameError: name 'URLError' is not defined` but is everything alright '-'.

Comment: hmmm! and another question: I put `if r.code == 200 or 401:
            print '[{}]: '.format(url), "Up!"
  else r.code == 404:
   print '[{}]: '.format(url), "Not Found!"`
but I got the error: `IndentationError: unexpected indent` What's wrong?

Comment: This `if r.code == 200 or 401:` is NOT how you do multiple equality checks. You should do this: `if r.code in (200, 401):`

Comment: You need to use `elif` instead of `else` because you want to specify an additional boolean condition. See edit.

Answer (score 33):

This might be a simple solution, here

```
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
```

you are using the `httpconnection` so no need to give url like, [http://OSMQuote.com](http://osmquote.com) but instead of that you need to give [OSMQuote.com](http://osmquote.com).

In short remove the `http://` and `https://` from your URL, because the `httplib` is considering `:` as a port number and the port number must be numeric,

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

nonnumeric port:

Solution :

> http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com")

Remove "**https://**" from Service URL or Endpoint and it will work.

https://appdotpy.wordpress.com/2020/07/04/errorsolved-nonnumeric-port/

Comment: Yes.. I think the lib just wants to get the scheme(http/https) from other param and join them together; so if you have http in url, lib gets `http://http://xxx` and parsing error.