# Python HTTP Client GET issue with port

Tags: python-3.x, http, client

I am trying to GET response from a login page

Here is the code i tried to use

```
import http.client
url ="https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url,port=None)
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
```

And this is the error i am getting

```
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F'
```

The get url in my code contains : its reading data after that as PORT even after passing an extra argument **port=None**

Can someone help me out of this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491814/httplib-invalidurl-nonnumeric-port Have you tried the second answer on this question with 17 votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just mention the host name and port in the constructor(
[Read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection)). 
Rest of the request can be given in the [request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request).You can view a lot of [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples) in the docs page.

You could pass the host name and rest of the request like this.

```
import http.client
url ="accounts.spotify.com"
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url,port=None)
conn.request("GET", "/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fwww.spotify.com%2Fus%2Faccount%2Foverview%2F")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
```

Output

```
200 OK
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly 

I also have one more doubt.. If i want to enable auto redirect to turn on in python how should i do... in c# it would be request.redirect = true, in python how would it look like ?

Comment: @BhanuTeja I believe it is set on by default.

Comment: ok if its set by default how would i stop it ? Stopiing auto redirect, any extra arguments for that

Comment: @BhanuTeja See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110498/is-there-an-easy-way-to-request-a-url-in-python-and-not-follow-redirects.